# Logo to Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

I am overriding the standard Account page.How to add the logo of Account and title of the record.For Example in standard Account page we have chatter and logo Account of Account and Title of Account.In my case I just need logo and title of account

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.name}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Phone}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the apex sectionheader to do this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >
<apex:sectionHeader title="Account" subtitle="{!Account.Name}"/>
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.name}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Phone}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```